# How to serialize an object into an array of bytes (Portable Class Library)

Tags: c#, serialization, portable-class-library

I have an object that I want to serialize into `byte[]` in order to save it or move it around. Let's assume it's:

```
public class Message
{
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }

    public byte[] Body { get; set; }
}

public enum MessageType : byte
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
}
```

My code is a .Net 4.5, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 PCL (Portable Class Library), and all the libraries, examples, and answers I came across don't work with PCL, mostly because of their use of `BinaryFormatter`, which is not available in PCL.

So, how to go about it?

Comment: Do you have access to change the code of the PCL?

Comment: have you looked into using `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: @Alex, yes I looked into it and was unable to make it work. I was getting XML-something exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a class that simple just write your own serializer using [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) (Both useable in PCL projects)

```
public class Message
{
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }

    public byte[] Body { get; set; }

    public byte[] Serialize()
    {
        //Data will be serialized in the format 
        //  - MessageType (1 byte)
        //  - BodyLength (4 bytes)
        //  - Body (x Bytes)

        //We allocate a fixed buffer as we know the size already.
        var buffer = new byte[Body.Length + 5];

        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer)
        {
            Serialize(ms);
        }

        //Return our buffer.
        return buffer 
    }

    //Just in case you have a stream instead of a byte[]
    public void Serialize(Stream stream)
    {
        using(var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            writer.Write((byte)this.MessageType);
            writer.Write(Body.Length);
            writer.Write(Body);
        }
    }

    public static Message Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return Message.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    //Just in case you have a stream instead of a byte[]
    public static Message Deserialize(Stream data)
    {
        var message = new Message();

        //Use the default text encoding (does not matter for us) and leave the stream open.
        using(var reader = new BinaryReader(data, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            //We do the same order of operations.
            message.MessageType = (MessageType)reader.ReadByte();
            var bodyLength = reader.ReadInt32();
            message.Body = reader.ReadBytes(bodyLength);
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

---

Here is a simplified version if you are never going to use Streams for deserializing.

```
    public byte[] Serialize()
    {
        //Data will be serialized in the format 
        //  - MessageType (1 byte)
        //  - Body (x Bytes)

        //We allocate a fixed buffer as we know the size already.
        var data = new byte[Body.Length + 1];

        data[0] = (byte)this.MessageType;
        //We copy the data from Body in to data starting at index 1 in data.
        Array.Copy(Body, 0, data, 1, Body.Length);    

        return data;
    }

    public static Message Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        var message = new Message();

        //We do the same order of operations.
        message.MessageType = (MessageType)data[0];

        //Create a new array and copy the body data in to it.
        var body = new byte[data.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(data, 1, body, 0, data.Length - 1);

        //Assign the body array to the property.
        message.Body = body;

        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would personally lose the `BodyLength`, as this isn't c. It's only necessary if there are other properties to serialize after the byte array.

Comment: @YoryeNathan If you are only ever passing in `byte[]` to the deserializer and that byte never contains extra data then yes you can. (there are a ton of other optimisations you could do too, like dropping the BinaryWriter/Reader and just using a array indexer for the message type and `Array.Copy` for the body) I chose to include it because I wanted to show the OP how he could deserialize from a Stream which happens much more often than having a `byte[]` of the serialized object and only that object.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, `BinaryReader` doesn't have a method that reads "the rest", am I right? If so, the alternative to having the length as part of the serialized object is to do subtraction; i.e., data-length - whatever-before-body-length... or am I missing something?

Comment: @TheBlueSky You are correct. However if you are just only going to have arrays passed in that only contains a single `Message` and nothing else the serializer methods can be simplified, I updated my answer with the simplified version (I also added seralziing to a stream in the complex version so you could pass in a `FileStream` or a `NetworkStream` and it would still work fine)